# Java hibernate query into ArrayList

Tags: java

I know this probably sounds quite basic but I am very new to Java.

I wish to set an objects field value to the same field in a new similar object.  How do I do this please.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have to be a little more specific about what you want to do. Your description is extremely vague.

Comment: I have an object with a field "createdon" which is a date held as a string I think and I wish to place its "createdon" value in a duplicate objects "createdon" field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment, since you are duplicating an instance, you should probably create a *copy constructor*.  That is a constructor that takes an instance of the class, and bases the fields of the new instance off the fields of the original.  [Here is a simple example](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=12).

However, if this instance is an object that is being saved, usually fields like `createDate` reflect the date of the copy, not the date of the original, but it doesn't have to be that way.